# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a problem about implementing two entities named for Country and State in Spring JPA.

I wrote a code to pose Country and State entities shown below.

Country Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY",catalog ="SPRINGANGULAR")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id","code","countryName"}, exclude = "states")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="COUNTRY_SEQ", sequenceName="COUNTRY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="COUNTRY_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="CODE")
    private String code;
    
    @Column(name="COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String countryName;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="country",
            cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<State> states = new HashSet<State>();

    public Country(String code, String countryName) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    
}
```

State Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STATE",catalog ="SPRINGANGULAR")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "stateName"})
public class State {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="STATE_SEQ", sequenceName="STATE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="STATE_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    public State(String stateName, Country country) {
        super();
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.country = country;
    }
    
}
```

Then I create a State Reporistory to get states by country code.

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "states", path = "states")
public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT s FROM State s \n" + 
           "LEFT JOIN Country c ON c.id = c.id \n" + 
           "WHERE c.code = :code \n" + 
           "ORDER BY s.id ASC")
    List<State> findByCountryCode(@RequestParam("code") String code);
}
```

Then I write a connection url in Postman to check if it works.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/states/findByCountryCode?code=BR
```

It throws an error

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'findByCountryCode'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "findByCountryCode"
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: you are trying to parse the value "findByCountryCode" to a numerical value. it is obvious that it isn't a numerical value, but text

Comment: @Stultuske How can I fix `List<State> findByCountryCode(@RequestParam("code") String code)` method?

Comment: are you sure SELECT s FROM STATE s is valid? seems a bit off

Comment: @Stultuske `SELECT s FROM STATE` is valid when I use thir url in Postman. `http://localhost:8080/api/states`

Comment: SELECT s FROM STATE is not the same as SELECT s FROM STATE s

Comment: This URL works: http://localhost:8080/states/search/findByCountryCode?code=BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is shown below.

I wrongly use this url `http://localhost:8080/api/states/findByCountryCode?code=BR`

Convert url

```
http://localhost:8080/api/states/findByCountryCode?code=BR`
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/api/states?code=BR
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a mix of native SQL and JPQL, definitely not valid. Here is the valid one:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM State s \n" + 
           "WHERE s.country.code = :code \n" + 
           "ORDER BY s.id ASC")
```

There is no need for explicit left join, it is done by `s.country` expression.

Also, there is no such thing as `LEFT JOIN  ON` in JPQL. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types) are some join examples

Also, the URL should be something like:

`http://localhost:8080/states/search/findByCountryCode?code=BR`

You are missing a `search` as path element.

Comment: I already tried this sql code and it also threw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a problem with the **REST controller**.
I assume you have a mapping for `/api/states/{id}` somewhere, like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/states/")
public class StateController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public State getState(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
       ...
    }
}
```

When you call `/api/states/findByCountryCode?code=BR`, it then interprets `findByCountryCode` as path variable `id` of type `long`, which will result in exactly this exception:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "findByCountryCode"
```

**Solution:**

- either restrict the `id` path parameter with a regex pattern (numeric), or
- **use a different path to query the states** (such as `/api/states?code=BR`)

The latter pattern is a common standard for **listing and finding resources**:

- no query parameters: list all
- with query parameters: list matching -> find functionality

So something like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<State> find(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code) {
       if (code != null) {
           // find by code
       } 
       else {
           // list all
       }
    }
```